# Error handling in SSIS Dynamic Connection manager

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012, msbi

I have a SSIS pckage in which i am fetching the data from 350 different oracle database hosted on Different server.
I have added a foreach loop container to fetch the data from different server and storing it into 1 database.
I want that if any of the connection fails then my package skip that connection and move it into the next connect, how can i implement that?

Answer (score 0):

If I was worried about it not working I would test with a try catch.

1. Create a variable called canConnect type boolean.
2. You probably already have this, but you need a connectionString variable type string
3. That connection string needs to be set on each iteration of foreach
4. Add a script task
5. Pass in canConnect as read/ write and connString as Read
6. Add the following code:

   ```
   Dts.Variables["canConnect"].Value = false;
   string cstr = Dts.Variables["connString"].Value;
   try
   {
        using(System.Data.OleDB.OleDbConnection conn = new System.Data.OleDB.OleDbConnection(cstr);)
         {
             conn.Open();
             Dts.Variables["canConnect"].Value = true;

         }
   }
   catch{}
   finally
   {conn.Close();}
   ```
7. Do something if you know canConnect = false